# How to get Commit Time of any committed offset of Kafka Using Kafka Admin Client in Java?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to get the commit time for a particular offset of a consumer group. I checked the Admin Client API's. The listConsumerGroupOffsets API's only returning the offset information. How can I get the timestamp (commit timestamp) of that offset for that particular consumer group ?

Answer (score 0):

Change visibility of internal topics by using following command:

```
echo "exclude.internal.topics=false" > /tmp/consumer.config
```

Use following command to see the commit time along with offset

```
kafka-console-consumer --consumer.config /tmp/consumer.config \
  --formatter "kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager\$OffsetsMessageFormatter" \
  --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
  --topic __consumer_offsets | grep <group_id>
```

Comment: I can get the commit time using console command as suggested by you. But I needed to achieve the same via Java Kafka Client

Comment: Doesn't work on Kafka 2.7.0: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager$OffsetsMessageFormatter`

Comment: Looks like with recent version the class package has changed to `kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager\$OffsetsMessageFormatter`

Comment: @Ananya How did you achieve it by Java Kafka Client?